# Fetch column from datafrom and use as array by python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fetch the column from dataframe to the array.

then make new array from this array attach to original dataframe.

My DataFrame(df) is like this.

```
   close        per
0  637.0  -0.156740
1  638.0    0.789889
2  633.0   -1.555210
3  643.0   -1.832061
4  655.0    0.000000
```

Then I try to fetch column from DataFrame and make moving average.

```
newarray =  pandas.rollling_mean(df.per,3) ## fetch array
```

then I want to attach this to original datafrom

```
df[sma] = newarray
```

What I want to get finally is like this

```
   close    per       sma
0  637.0   -0.156740  636 
1  638.0    0.789889  638
2  633.0   -1.555210  643.6
3  643.0   -1.832061  nan 
4  655.0    0.000000  nan
```

However I think there is something comfusion with dataframe and array.

Maybe I might be misunderstanding.

How can I correct this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on your goals:

```
In [39]: df['sma'] = df.close.rolling(3).mean()

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
   close       per         sma
0  637.0 -0.156740         NaN
1  638.0  0.789889         NaN
2  633.0 -1.555210  636.000000
3  643.0 -1.832061  638.000000
4  655.0  0.000000  643.666667
```

or:

```
In [36]: df['sma'] = df.close.rolling(3, center=True).mean().shift(-1)

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   close       per         sma
0  637.0 -0.156740  636.000000
1  638.0  0.789889  638.000000
2  633.0 -1.555210  643.666667
3  643.0 -1.832061         NaN
4  655.0  0.000000         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks it works , I need to change `shift(-1)` value according to average period as `Averageperiod / 2 - 1 ` ,so it looks a bit tricky for me. I need to understand how `center=True function` works.

Answer (score 1):

**Not for beginners**

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as strided

v = np.append(df.close.values, [np.nan] * 2)
s = v.strides[0]

df.assign(sma=strided(v, (v.size - 2, 3), (s, s)).mean(1))

   close       per         sma
0  637.0 -0.156740  636.000000
1  638.0  0.789889  638.000000
2  633.0 -1.555210  643.666667
3  643.0 -1.832061         NaN
4  655.0  0.000000         NaN
```